# SQL query returns same value in each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'm having an issue with SQL joins in a query that is designed to query the Post table having been joined to the comment, click and vote table and return stats about each posts activity. My query below is what I've been using.

```
SELECT
    p.PostID, 
    p.Title, 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(cm.CommentID) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(cm.CommentID)
    END AS CommentCount, 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(cl.ClickID) IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE COUNT(cl.ClickID)
    END AS ClickCount, 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(vt.Value) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(vt.Value)
    END AS VoteScore
FROM 
    Post p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment cm ON p.PostID = cm.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Click cl ON p.PostID = cl.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Vote vt ON p.PostID = vt.PostID
GROUP BY
    p.PostID, 
    p.Title
```

Yields the following result

```
| PostID | CommentCount | ClickCount | VoteScore |
|--------|--------------|------------|-----------|
| 41     |            60|          60|         60|
| 50     |          1683|        1683|       1683|
```

This, I know isn't correct. When comment out all but one of the joins:

```
SELECT
     p.PostID 
    ,p.Title 
    ,CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(cm.CommentID) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(cm.CommentID)
     END AS CommentCount
/*
    ,CASE
        WHEN COUNT(cl.ClickID) IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE COUNT(cl.ClickID)
     END AS ClickCount
    ,CASE
        WHEN SUM(vt.Value) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(vt.Value)
     END AS VoteScore
 */
FROM 
    Post p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment cm ON p.PostID = cm.PostID
/*
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Click cl ON p.PostID = cl.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Vote vt ON p.PostID = vt.PostID
 */
GROUP BY
    p.PostID, 
    p.Title
```

I get

```
| PostID | CommentCount |
|--------|--------------|
| 41     |             3|
```

Which is correct.  Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you are using a case expression here. ISNULL(COUNT(cm.CommendID), 0) as CommentCount is a lot cleaner and simpler. My guess is you have some logical problems in your joins but without some ddl and sample data it is really hard to offer much help here.

Comment: Your `left join` is probably on a 1:many relationship, which causes your records in `post` and `comment` to duplicate to accomodate all of the extra records from `click` or `vote`. Try, for you `Count()` aggregates to do a `Count(Distinct cm.commentid)` and `Count(Distinct cl.ClickID)`. I'm betting your `Sum()` is fine as is since `Vote` is probably the most granular, but that's a guess.

Comment: As already explained, you are counting duplicates. And I guess that `vote` is always 1, so `sum` gets the same result as `count`. And the `case` around `count` is superfluous, because a count is never null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result that is being returned is expected because the query is producing a Cartesian (or semi-Cartesian) product. The query is basically telling MySQL to perform "cross join" operations on the rows returned from `comment`, `click` and `vote`.

Each row returned from `comment` (for a given postid) gets matched to each row from `click` (for the same postid). And then each of the rows in that result gets matched to each row from `vote` (for the same postid).

So, for two rows from `comment`, and three rows from `click` and four rows from `vote`, that will return a total of 24 (=2x3x4) rows.

The usual pattern for fixing this is to avoid the cross join operations.

There are a couple of approaches to do that.

---

**correlated subqueries in select list**

If you only need a single aggregate (e.g. COUNT or SUM) from each of the three tables, you could remove the joins, and use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list. Write a query that gets a count for a single postid, for example

```
 SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM comment cmt
  WHERE cmt.postid = ?
```

Then wrap that query in parens, and reference it in the SELECT list of another query, and replace the question mark to a reference to postid from the table referenced in the outer query.

```
SELECT p.postid
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM comment cmt
           WHERE cmt.postid = p.postid
       ) AS comment_count
  FROM post p
```

Repeat the same pattern to get "counts" from `click` and `vote`.

The downside of this approach is that the subquery in the SELECT list will get executed for *each* row returned by the outer query. So this can get expensive if the outer query returns a lot of rows. If `comment` is a large table, then to get reasonable performance, it's critical that there's appropriate index available on `comment`.

---

**pre-aggregate in inline views**

Another approach is to "pre-aggregate" the results inline views. Write a query that returns the comment count for postid. For example

```
SELECT cmt.postid 
     , COUNT(1) 
  FROM comment cmt
 GROUP BY cmt.postid
```

Wrap that query in parens and reference it in the FROM clause of another query, assign an alias. The inline view query basically takes the place of a table in the outer query.

```
SELECT p.postid
     , cm.postid
     , cm.comment_count
  FROM post p 
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT cmt.postid 
              , COUNT(1) AS comment_count
           FROM comment cmt
          GROUP BY cmt.postid
       ) cm
    ON cm.postid = p.postid
```

And repeat that same pattern for `click` and `vote`. The trick here is the GROUP BY clause in the inline view query that guarantees that it won't return any duplicate postid values. And a cartesian product (cross join) to that won't produce duplicates.

The downside of this approach is that the derived table won't be indexed. So for a large number of postid, it may be expensive to perform the join in the outer query. (More recent versions of MySQL partially address this downside, by automatically creating an appropriate index.)

(We can workaround this limitation by creating a temporary able with an appropriate index. But this approach requires additional SQL statements, and is not entirely suitable for an adhoc single statement.  But for batch processing of large sets, the additional complexity can be worth it for some significant performance gains.

---

**collapse Cartesian product by DISTINCT values**

As an entirely different approach, leave your query like it is, with the cross join operations, and allow MySQL to produce the Cartesian product. Then the aggregates in the SELECT list can filter out the duplicates. This requires that you have a column (or expression produced) from `comment` that is UNIQUE for each row in comment for a given postid.

```
SELECT p.postid
     , COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS comment_count
  FROM post p
  LEFT
  JOIN comment c
    ON c.postid = p.postid
 GROUP BY p.postid
```

The big downside of this approach is that it has the potential to produce a *huge* intermediate result, which is then "collapsed" with a "Using filesort" operation (to satisfy the GROUP BY). And this can be pretty expensive for large sets.

---

This isn't an exhaustive list of all possible query patterns to achieve the result you are looking to return. Just a representative sampling.

Comment: Very good explanation of the issue itself and its different solution patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT
    p.PostID, 
    p.Title,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comment cm
    WHERE cm.PostID = p.PostID) AS CommentCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Click cl 
    WHERE  p.PostID = cl.PostID) AS ClickCount ,
   (SELECT SUM(vt.Value) FROM Vote vt 
    WHERE p.PostID = vt.PostID) AS VoteScore 
FROM 
    Post p
```

The problem with your query is that the second and third `LEFT JOIN` operations duplicate records: after the first `LEFT JOIN` has been applied you have, for example 3, records for post having `PostID = 41`. The second `LEFT JOIN` now joins to these 3 records, so `PostID = 41` is used **3 times** in the second `LEFT JOIN`.

If there is a 1:many relationship *directly* between (`Post`, `Comment`), (`Post`, `Click`) and (`Post`, `Vote`), then the above query will most probably give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn’t doing what you think it is doing. When you join and count rows like this, you’re creating a new dataset with x rows, and then just counting the rows in that dataset three times. Hence you get the same count three times.

What you want to do is only count the rows for comments and and clicks where the left join found data in those two tables, for example:

```
SELECT
   p.PostID 
   ,p.Title 
   ,COUNT(CASE 
      WHEN cm.PostID IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END) AS CommentCount

  ,COUNT(CASE
     WHEN cl.PostID IS NULL THEN 0 
     ELSE 1
   END) AS ClickCount
  ,SUM(CASE
     WHEN vt.PostID IS NULL THEN 0
     ELSE ISNULL(vt.Value,0)
   END) AS VoteScore

FROM 
  Post p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment cm ON p.PostID = cm.PostID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Click cl ON p.PostID = cl.PostID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Vote vt ON p.PostID = vt.PostID
GROUP BY
  p.PostID, 
  p.Title
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been explained already what is wrong with your query: With say 3 comments, 5 clicks and 4 votes (each vote with a value of 1) for postid 41, you get 3x5x4=60 counts for the first and second count expression and 3x5x4x1=60 for the sum.

When dealing with several outer joins in combination with aggregation, you must not join tables first and aggregate later, but aggregate first and join the aggregates then:

```
select
  p.postid, 
  p.title, 
  coalesce(cm.cnt, 0) as commentcount, 
  coalesce(cl.cnt, 0) as clickcount, 
  coalesce(vt.total, 0) as votescore 
from post p
left outer join (select postid, count(*) as cnt from comment group by postid) cm
  on cm.postid = p.postid
left outer join (select postid, count(*) as cnt from click group by postid) cl
  on cl.postid = p.postid
left outer join (select postid, sum(value) as total from vote group by postid) vt
  on vt.postid = p.postid;
```

Answer (score 1):

COUNT counts non null values. But setting the nulls to 0, they count. Change your counts to SUM and move them outside the case when and I think it will fix the issue.

EG

```
SELECT
    p.PostID, 
    p.Title, 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN cm.CommentID IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE cm.CommentID
    END) AS CommentCount, 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN cl.ClickID IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE cl.ClickID
    END) AS ClickCount, 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN SUM(vt.Value IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE SUM(vt.Value
    END) AS VoteScore
FROM 
    Post p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment cm ON p.PostID = cm.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Click cl ON p.PostID = cl.PostID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Vote vt ON p.PostID = vt.PostID
GROUP BY
    p.PostID, 
    p.Title
```